# How do i test a Net Present Value with pytest or doctest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, miniconda

I have a problem, I'm studying programming, and I have a question about testing. I want to perform testing on a code I have for calculating net present value, but I don't know how. Tutorials always demonstrate testing with simple functions like addition and subtraction, but the code I have is simple but not that simple. I tried with `pytest` and `doctest`, but I feel overwhelmed. Help

```
    continue_flag = 0
while continue_flag == 0:
    # Validate initial investment
    while True:
        try:
            investment = float(input('Enter the initial investment: '))
            if investment >= 0:
                break
            else:
                print("The investment must be a positive value.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number for the investment.")

    # Validate discount rate
    while True:
        try:
            rate = float(input('Enter the discount rate (5% to 30% as a decimal): '))
            if 0.05 <= rate <= 0.30:
                break
            else:
                print("The rate must be between 0.05 and 0.30.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number for the discount rate.")

    # Validate number of periods
    while True:
        try:
            periods = int(input('Enter the number of periods to evaluate: '))
            if periods > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("The number of periods must be positive.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid integer for the number of periods.")

    # Initialize variables
    accumulator2 = 0
    i = 0

    # Calculate NPV
    while i < periods:
        i += 1
        while True:
            try:
                cash_flow = float(input(f"Enter the cash flow for period {i}: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid number for the cash flow.")

        accumulator1 = cash_flow / (1 + rate) ** i
        accumulator2 += accumulator1

    npv = accumulator2 - investment
    npv = round(npv, 2)
    print(f'The NPV is: {npv}')

    # Ask if they want to continue
    while True:
        try:
            continue_flag = int(input('Do you want to continue? YES(0) NO(1): '))
            if continue_flag == 0 or continue_flag == 1:
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter 0 to continue or 1 to finish.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter 0 to continue or 1 to finish.")

print("Goodbye!")
```

I tried to learn from videos `pytest`, `doctest` and `unittest` but they always test with simple functions

Comment: The `input()` is interfering with your desire to call this from a `unittest.TestCase` method. Write an interactive driver method which solicits numbers with `input` and then calls the "real" `npv` function, passing along those numbers as input arguments. Then write a testcase method which similarly calls `npv(investment, rate, periods)`.